# How to disable button in Flutter based on state

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I made a delete button that pops up a dialog and makes you record the reason for the delete.  I only want the submit button enabled if the user enters a reason.  Here is what I have for that widget:

```
  class _DeleteCrewMemberWidgetState extends State<DeleteCrewMemberWidget> {
  var note = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool enabled = note.length >= 10;

    // delete this member
    delete() {
      Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
    }

    print(enabled);
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Delete ${widget.position.name}'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text(
                  'Please enter a reason for not needing this crew member.'),
              TextField(
                maxLines: 4,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  note = value;
                  print(note);
                }),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your reason here',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: enabled ? () => delete() : null,
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run it and type in a note, the button stays disabled.  I print the value of the state on build, and it does change to enabled as I type.  When I get out of the icon and back in, it then shows enabled, even though the note is empty.  But it never changes while I'm typing the note.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you need two things here

1. An Alert Dialog wrapped in a Stateful Builder to get its state updated.
2. Reset the value of `enabled` and `note` once the dialog is closed. So wait  for the Dialog to close and reset the value as per your need.

Here's the modified code :

```
class _DeleteCrewMemberWidgetState extends State<DeleteCrewMemberWidget> {
  var note = '';
  bool enabled = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //No longer needed here
    //bool enabled = note.length >= 10;
    delete() {
      Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
    }

    /// print(enabled);
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
        onPressed: () async {
          String? input = await showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Delete Some Name'),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                          'Please enter a reason for not needing this crew member.'),
                      TextField(
                        maxLines: 4,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          if (value.length >= 10) {
                            enabled = true;
                          } else {
                            enabled = false;
                          }
                          print(value);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'Enter your reason here',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                      child: const Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: enabled ? () => delete() : null,
                      child: const Text('OK'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );

          //You can add a conditional here to check the return String and enable disable likewise
          note = '';
          enabled = false;

          setState(() {});
        });
  }
}
```

**Note**: You do not always need to wrap your variables with setState to update. Just calling the setState will automatically update the widget tree with updated variables.

Comment: Thank you.  It works perfectly.  Could you please explain why my solution didn't work?  It seems like it should, so I must be missing something.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: 1. Your code was doing multiple things inside of build method which is not suggested.
2. You were not resetting the variables on dialog close, so when you reopen, the OK button is still enabled. The suggested code waits for the dialog to close and reset the variables thereafter according to the need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but disable the "OK" button until the user enters a reason:

```
  onPressed: enabled ? () => note.length >= 10 ? delete() : null : null,
```

your code:

```
class _DeleteCrewMemberWidgetState extends State<DeleteCrewMemberWidget> {
  var note = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool enabled = note.length >= 10;

    // delete this member
    delete() {
      Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
    }

    print(enabled);
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Delete ${widget.position.name}'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text(
                  'Please enter a reason for not needing this crew member.'),
              TextField(
                maxLines: 4,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  note = value;
                  print(note);
                }),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your reason here',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: enabled ? () => note.length >= 10 ? delete() : null : null,
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

See if I could help you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correction with TextEditingController:

```
class _DeleteCrewMemberWidgetState extends State<DeleteCrewMemberWidget> {

  final noteController = TextEditingController();
  bool noteIsValid = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    noteController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // delete this member
    delete() {
      Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
    }

    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Delete ${widget.position.name}'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text(
                  'Please enter a reason for not needing this crew member.'),
              TextField(
                controller: noteController,
                maxLines: 4,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your reason here',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: noteIsValid ? () => delete() : null,
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    noteController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        noteIsValid = noteController.text.length >= 10;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This corrected one does not work.  It behaves just like my original one.  The one before the corrected one works great.